# How does the instructor using extrude get this mesh shape

Tags: modeling

I'm watching a tutorial, and the instructor is using extrude method to get a notch in a sphere using the extrude method. He's going to fast to understand how he achieves this. Its the 02:58, where he says he's going to extrude that little bit.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FV66bVT1Tog&t=180s

[image]
[image]

This is what I select on my sphere, and the result I get when extruding.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The video is too fast to see the different operations, but you can select the 4 faces, press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and <kbd>Enter</kbd> right away:

[image]

Then <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to flatten:

[image]

Enable the *Snap to Vertex* and the *Auto Merge* option, move down and snap to the vertices:

[image]

Remove the 2 front faces:

[image]